# How to move and rename files based on parent folder in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, file, command-line, directory

I have a folder named `photos` with the following structure:

```
00001/photo.jpg
00002/photo.jpg
00003/photo.jpg
```

I want to:

1. Rename the file within the folder (which called `photo.jpg`) to parent folder.
2. Move it a folder up.
3. Remove the parent folder.

So the `photos` folder would be something like this:

```
00001.jpg
00002.jpg
00003.jpg
```

**How can I do this in Terminal in Linux?**

*Note.* There are 100000+ such folders in `photos`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Post edited since I've read in a comment that you have 100000+ such directories.**

Do *not* use any method that involves bash globbing, it would be terribly slow and inefficient. Instead, use this `find` command, from within the `photos` directory:

```
find -regex '\./[0-9]+' -type d -exec mv -n -- {}/photo.jpg {}.jpg \; -empty -delete
```

I've use the `-n` option to `mv` so that we don't overwrite existing files. Use it if your version of `mv` supports it. You can also use the `-v` option so that `mv` is verbose and you see what's happening:

```
find -regex '\./[0-9]+' -type d -exec mv -nv -- {}/photo.jpg {}.jpg \; -empty -delete
```

Read the previous command as:

- `-regex '\./[0-9]+'`: find everything in current directory that has only digits in its name
- `-type d`: and it must be a directory
- `-exec mv -n -- {}/photo.jpg {}.jpg \;`: move the `photo.jpg` file in this directory into the parent directory, with name: `dirname.jpg`
- `-empty`: if the directory is now empty...
- `-delete`: ...delete it.

After that, you might want to see which directories have not been deleted (because e.g., it contained more files than just the `photo.jpg` file):

```
find -regex '\./[0-9]+' -type d
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

```
cd $toTheRootFolderWhichYouHaveALLtheFolders #00001, 00002
mv 00001/photo.jpg 00001.jpg
```

Or you can use this bash script in the "photos" directory:

```
for entry in ./*; 
 do  
    mv "$entry"/photo.jpg "$entry".jpg ;
    rm -rf "$entry";
 done
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have 100,000+ folders like this. Executing one by one?

Comment: create a `wtv.sh` file, edit with your favorite text editor and paste the code with `#!/bin/bash` as header. Then set the previllages to execute the script `chmod +x wtv.sh` and you're good to go.

Comment: or in the "root folder" which you have the other folder type `sh` and paste the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
find . -type f | while read -r file; do mv "$file" "${file%/*}"".jpg" ; done
```

Once you have all the files renamed and moved up to the parent folder, you can run the following command to delete all empty folders.

```
find . -type d -empty -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Please remember that the above solution is only for the structure you have presented. If you have multiple files in any of the sub-folder and you want it to rename it to parent directory name it will get overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way that I've used takes the output from something like `ls */*.jpg` (or just `ls */*`) and process the output to form a move command like `mv 00001/photo.jpg ./00001.jpg`, and you can then easily clean-up the empty folders with a similar approach using `rmdir 00001`.

To do it this using `awk` at the bash terminal type:

```
ls */* | awk -F'/' '{print "mv " $0 " ./" $1 "_" $2 }' | bash
ls */ | awk -F'/' '{print "rmdir " $1 }' | bash
```

You can easily preview your commands before running them by leaving off the `| bash` at the end of the line (to see what the generated commands are and fix syntax errors before you pipe them into bash to have them executed).

Unfortunately, the output of `ls */` includes empty lines that will mess with your `rmdir`, but won't stop it from having the required effect.

I find that this approach is quite powerful/flexible and easier than scripting a loop. Use the method that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop, and `printf -v` to zero pad the counter. Example:

```
for ((i=1;i<4;i++))
do 
    printf -v num "%05d" "$i"; 
    mv "$num"/photo.jpg "$num".jpg
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this should do what you want.

```
# Setup test data according to your structure
$ mkdir 00001 00002 00003 
$ touch 00001/photo.jpg 00002/photo.jpg 00003/photo.jpg

# Rename, these are the commands you'll want to run to rename
$ ls ?????/photo.jpg | xargs -I {} sh -c 'mv {} $(echo {} | sed "s,/photo,,")'
$ rmdir  ?????

# Verify that the renames went ok
$ ls
00001.jpg   00002.jpg   00003.jpg
```

Comment: @mrz The mkdir/touch thing is to set up files according to his question to demo the rename in the `#Rename` section. Edited to make that even clearer. I just find that renaming 100k files is a bit scary without a test case you can use first.

Comment: he doesn't need to setup his "spec" since he already have his spec, answers should address OP's spec all the time... nice renaming though